# List of lists C

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to make list made of lists and the inner list is made of items.

Union of datatype:

```
typedef union s_datatype {
    int t_int;
    char* t_char;
    double t_double;
    bool t_bool;
} t_datatype;
```

Structure of item:

```
typedef struct s_token {
    int y;
    int type;
    t_datatype value;
    struct s_token *next;
} t_token;
```

Structure of inner list:

```
typedef struct s_line {
    int x;
    int depth;
    int type;
    int number_of_tokens;
    t_token*head;
    struct s_line *next;
} t_line;
```

Structure of the final list:

```
typedef struct s_tokenized_code {
    int number_of_lines;
    t_line*head;
} t_tokenized_code;
```

Let's say that I want to add new "line" and into that line, I want to insert the "token". But I don't know, how to put this together. Can you help me? I'm not sure how to alloc this and how to work with this list of lists.

EDIT: Structure modified

Comment: Start with a simple single list first to get the idea.

Comment: ... and don't hide pointers behind a typedef. It will only confuse you and others.

Comment: Something it looks like you're missing: When you create the head of a list, you usually want that to be a pointer, too. I suppose you could make it fully formed, but then you have to have different code in order to access the first element of your list. So, for example, `t_line * head` or `t_token * head`. This goes directly hand-in-hand with @wildplasser commenting about not putting a typedef over a pointer.

Comment: @Johan Nelson So I should remove the pointer before the typedef, and add the pointer where you said, right?

Comment: When I hear "list of a list" that reminds me of something that could be structured somewhat like a matrix, e.g., imagine head nodes (say struct Node{}) distributed as the start of each column and then each Node also has Node{ Node*next} but then also includes a below Node: struct Node {Node* next; Node* below}, does this help envision what your trying to do?

Comment: @roybatty Exactly. I'm writing an interpeter in C, this should distribute the tokens to lines, and then link the lines together to one big list for easier access.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know, how to (i want to insert items to the end of list, not beginning):

```
t_token*init_token (int y, int type, t_datatype value) {
    t_token*token = malloc(sizeof(struct s_token));
    if (token == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    token->y = y;
    token->type = type;
    token->value = value;
    token->next = NULL;
    return token;
}

t_line*init_line (int x, int depth, int type) {
    t_line*line = malloc(sizeof(struct s_line));
    if (line == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    line->x = x;
    line->depth = depth;
    line->type = type;
    line->number_of_tokens = 0;
    line->head = NULL;
    line->next = NULL;
    return line;
}

t_tokenized_code*init_code (void) {
    t_tokenized_code*code = malloc(sizeof(struct s_tokenized_code));
    if (code == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    code->number_of_lines = 0;
    code->head = NULL;
    return code;
}

void insert_token (t_line*line, t_token*token) {
    if (token != NULL) {
        if (line->head == NULL){
            line->head = token;
            line->number_of_tokens += 1;
            return;
        }
        t_token*tmp = line->head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = token;
        line->number_of_tokens += 1;
    }
}

void insert_line (t_tokenized_code*code, t_line*line) {
    if (line != NULL) {
        if (code->head == NULL) {
            code->head = line;
            code->number_of_lines += 1;
            return;
        }
        t_line*tmp = code->head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = line;
        code->number_of_lines += 1;
    }
}

void free_code (t_tokenized_code*source) {
    if (source == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    t_line*line;
    t_token*token;
    while ((line = source->head) != NULL) {
        while ((token = line->head) != NULL) {
            line->head = token->next;
            free(token);
        }
        source->head = line->next;
        free(line);
    }
    free(source);
}
```

Let's make a simple test - Adding 2 tokens to the first line and 3 tokens to the second line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void) {
    t_tokenized_code*source = init_code();
    t_line*line = init_line(0,0,3);
    if (line == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    insert_line(source, line);
    t_datatype tt;

    tt.t_char = "first";
    t_token*token = init_token(0,6, tt);
    if (token == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    insert_token(line, token);

    tt.t_char = "second";
    token = init_token(1,6, tt);
    insert_token(line, token);

    line = init_line(1,0,3);
    insert_line(source, line);

    tt.t_char = "third";
    token = init_token(0,6, tt);
    insert_token(line, token);

    tt.t_char = "fourth";
    token = init_token(1,6, tt);
    insert_token(line, token);

    tt.t_char = "fifth";
    token = init_token(2,6, tt);
    insert_token(line, token);

    line = source->head;
    while (line != NULL) {
        printf("****\n");
        token = line->head;
        while (token != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", token->value.t_char);
            token = token->next;
        }
        line = line->next;
    }
    free_code (source);
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be following:

```
****
first
second
****
third
fourth
fifth
```

Comment: Why is most of the code using typedef name `t_token`, while `sizeof` under `malloc` uses `struct s_token` instead? Same with `t_line` and `t_tokenized_code`. Why the inconsistency?

Comment: Also, in the original question you said that you want to add a new line and insert a token into that new line. I don't see you "add a new line" in the answer you posted. So, how is it "solved" then?

Comment: so `sizeof(t_token)` is the same as `sizeof(struct s_token)` ?

it's solved by calling `init_code()` which returns initialized code, then `init_line(..)` which returns the line, now we need to add the line to the structure: `insert_line(..)` and then we need to initialize token `init_token(..)` and add the token to the line `insert_token(..)`